# Python AttributeError on empty dictionary in class - trying to add to it

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes, instance, attributeerror

I'm sort of newish to Python, I've hit a really weird problem with my dictionary that I just can't seem to figure out.

Basically I have a class called **World** which has a dictionary `self.islands = {}` the problem is when I want to add an instance of my **Island** class using the method `addIsland(island)` in **World** I get the error:

> AttributeError: World instance has no attribute 'islands'

on the line:

```
self.islands[island.name] = island
```

self.islands definitely exists because I initialize it in **World**'s `__init__` as follows:

```
class World():
    def __init__(showBase, self):        
        self.islands = {}
        ...
```

The addIsland method is:

```
def addIsland(self, island):
    island.setWorld(self)
    self.islands[island.name] = island
```

And that method is called from the **base** class's `__init__` (which main runs) as follows:

```
self.world = World(self)
self.setupIslands()
```

self.setupIslands() looks like:

```
def setupIslands(self):
    #Island 1
    island1 = IslandCross()
    self.world.addIsland(island1)
```

Sorry if it is a bit confusing but basically I've got 3 classes, the base one that has a main, in it's `__init__` it calls `self.world = World(self)` then `self.setupIslands()`.

**World's** `__init__` has the line `self.islands = {}` and the method `addIsland()` which tries to add an **Island** to the dictionary with the key as the island's name (`island.name`) and it's value as the island instance itself.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm pretty sure I've got this kind of setup working in other places in my projects.

I bet it's something stupid and simple isn't it :)

Thanks for your time,

InfinitiFizz

Comment: Note that lowerCamelCase is not a standard for Python in most cases}. You should use variables and method names like "setup_islands", "is_land", etc. You can use CamelCase for Class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The self-reference is the *first* argument to methods.

```
def __init__(self, showBase):
```

Comment: Gaaaaaaaaaaaah! Thank you very much! I've written class ****(self, showBase): about 200 times as well! It must be the lack of sleep!

Thanks so much for the help @Ignacio :)